# dockle found suspicious file -do not store key/credential

Tags: azure-storage-files

[image: dockle Error message]

So I am getting this error as shown in an image from Dockle while running the pipeline.
This error was thrown after I added the package azure-storage-file-share.
I am not pushing any .env file.
How to tell Dockle that `settings.py` needs to be skipped?
The suppress recommendation goes where?
Can anyone recommend how this can be dealt with?

Note I have docker file for python